# How to make string array in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I want to make a array of string in which I want to save names of players of a cricket team. I want to save this in the form of array like below:

```
player[1]= sachin;
player[2]= john smith;
```

I used program below but I am getting following error:

```
Error   1
error C2661: 'std::basic_istream>::getline' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string player[3];
    int i;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        std::getline(cin, player);
    }
}
```

How can I save string array like we do with numerical array.

Comment: An array is an array is an array. They are all the same no matter the type, which means they all start at index zero.

Comment: Use container classes (`std::array` and/or `std::vector`), also `std::getline` takes a `std::string`, not an array of them.

Comment: you forgot to add `[i]` to the end of player.

Comment: _`for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)`_ Take care, indices should range from `0` to `2` actually.

Comment: But there would be 11 players in a cricket team right ? Why do you have an array of only 3 players here ? :-)

Comment: If I recall correctly, that is not how getline() is called.

Comment: why do you have using namespace std; in your main loop?

Comment: @DurgeshTanwar [here's a completely working version](http://ideone.com/MsEP67). Voted to close your question for trivial typos now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i <= 2;`
   i++)
2. `getline()` often causes errors and it wont simply work if you are using some flavor of Linux.
3. You are not indexing the array properly as in it should have been `player[i]` instead of just `player`.
4. if you are using `using namespace std;` then a better way of declaring is to declare it outside the main function.

Following code should do what you are trying to do.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string player[3];
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cin >> player [i];
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Secondly, getline often causes errors and it wont simply work if you are using some flavor of Linux."_ Uhm what please? Could you elaborate that (tell any facts). I never experienced `std::getline()` behaving differently on _some flavor of Linux_. Not even with recent standard compiler versions (after Turbo C++ maybe).

Comment: And this as well. "4.if you are using using namespace std; then a better way of declaring is to declare it outside the main function"